# Notion Api - Export PDF

Tags: notion-api

Is it possible to download a Notion page as PDF via the API?
Just like the Export -> PDF function that is available in the UI?

I am trying to automate the exporting process.
I have searched the Notion API but could not find anything.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: No, @FilledStacks. Unfortunately not.